# ASP.NET ListView Validation

Tags: asp.net

I need to validate the email address that are semicolon separated using ListView.

> e.g.
>   abc@email.com;abded@email.com;dfds@dfd.com
>   etc.

Is there any event that I can use on code behind as I can't seem to get it working..

Comment: Using Listview in the sense when the user selects any item in the ListView?

Comment: I would think `ItemUpdating` or `ItemInserting` is where you should check.

Comment: @kalyan, using ListView when user edit or add new items. This is where I have to check email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) control. And handle its [ServerValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx) event.

Refer to [How to: Validate with a Custom Function for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)